# Combining multiple sources in a single gulp chain

Tags: javascript, gulp

How can I combine multiple **sources** in a single gulp **pipe** chain? For example I have:

```
gulp.task('compressJS', function () {
    gulp.src('client/js/source/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('app'))
        .pipe(ngmin())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: ".min.js"
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'))
        .pipe(gulp.src('client/views/index.html'))
        .pipe(replace(/app\-[a-fA-F0-9]\.min\.js/, 'app-prod.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/build'))
        .pipe(gulp.src('client/js/rev-manifest.json', {
             read: false
         }))
        .pipe(rimaf());
});
```

Getting error:

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
```

Answer (score 2):

The most common solution to this problem that I have seen is by leveraging [`gulp-filter`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter). The idea is that your `gulp.src` is a lot more broad, but your filters allow you to process the more specific subsets.

For example, using your code:

```
   gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');

   gulp.task('compressJS', function () {

       jsFilter = gulpFilter('client/js/source/**/*.js');
       clientFilter = gulpFilter('client/views/index.html');

       gulp.src('client/**/*')
           .pipe(jsFilter)
           .pipe(concat('app'))
           .pipe(ngmin())
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(rev())
           .pipe(rename({
               extname: ".min.js"
           }))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'))
           .pipe(rev.manifest())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'))
           .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
           .pipe(clientFilter)
           .pipe(gulp.src('client/views/index.html'))
           .pipe(replace(/app\-[a-fA-F0-9]\.min\.js/, 'app-prod.min.js'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('client/build'))
           .pipe(gulp.src('client/js/rev-manifest.json', {
               read: false
           }))
           .pipe(clientFilter.restore())
           .pipe(rimaf());
    });
```